# Configuration location for RocketApp on MacOS

Tags: rocket.chat

I'm using https://github.com/RocketChat on MacOS. Where does it store configured servers? I would like to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

It's there: `/Users/[user]/Library/Containers/chat.rocket/Data/Library/Application Support/Rocket.Chat/config.json`

Answer (score 0):

The correct directory is now `~/Library/Application\ Support/Rocket.Chat`